# Pull Value After String

Tags: regex

Please could someone assist with the following? I'm looking to pull values for Applicant Two, so I would need the regex to ignore Applicant One and pull the value after First Name: I would be left with "Joe" for example not "Marie".

> Applicant One
>
> Title: Miss
>
> First Name: Marie
>
> Surname: Miller
>
> DOB: 01-01-1982
>
> Applicant Two
>
> Title: Mr
>
> First Name: Joe
>
> Surname: Blogss
>
> DOB: 19-09-1983

Comment: Welcome to SO! What have you tried so far? Can you show us? What program / language is the regex for? Syntax can differ based on context...

Comment: I'm using it alongside a program "G-Lock Software Email Processor" which is used to extract content from emails, I'm not sure of the language/context it uses?

Comment: If you can use [capturing groups](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html) for extraction try something like [`^Applicant Two\s*\r?\n(?:(?!Applicant).*\r?\n)*?First Name: *(.+)`](https://regex101.com/r/gpIpDh/2/). Assuming your tool uses `.NET` or `PCRE` regex flavor.

Comment: Just for reference, here's a manual for the software, describing what's supported in the regex flavour: https://www.glocksoft.com/mirror1/EmailProcessorManual.pdf

Answer (score 0):

in every iteration you could pull out a line behind "Applicant Two:"

`(.*)(Applicant Two)([\s\S]*?)^([^\n]+)$`

[image]